# Intent To Start Activity Not Working

Tags: java, android, class, manifest

I am trying to start an android activity name 'TheGame' from the activity 'SelectionFragment' with a button who's ID is 'startGame'
The SelectionFragment file's public class is :

```
public class SelectionFragment extends Fragment {
```

This is the code that contains the Intent:

```
public void startTheGame (View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TheGame.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

And this is what my Manifest file looks like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.alexlamond.higherorlower"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/highlowlogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.alexlamond.higherorlower.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.alexlamond.higherorlower.TheGame"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_the_game" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

My issue is that the Intent will not work, when I got to Eclipse's suggestion of how to fix it, it says:

The constructor Intent(SelectionFragment, Class) is undefined

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: We can only guess, because you haven't told us what the problem is.  My guess is that you cal this inside an onClickListener in which case replace `this` with `<name of activity>.this`

Comment: Sorry @Simon, I'll add that now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onClick` attribute must match by exact naming to a public method that has the same name. You have attribute `android:onClick="TheGame"` and the method signature is `public void startTheGame (View view)`. Change the `onClick` attribute value to `"startTheGame"`.

However, I would rather use `View.OnClickListener` instead of setting the `onClick` attribute because:

1. On the long run you may reuse/move/change this layout and you will end-up with the same error.
2. You might do some refactoring and you might change this method by accident or not, and the compiler will not complain.
3. Setting this type of linkage between UI and model seems to me a violation of `MVC`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are starting activity from your fragment, try this:

```
public void startTheGame (View view) {

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TheGame.class);
startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: I have tried adding this code and the LogCat says: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method TheGame(View) in the activity class com.alexlamond.higherorlower.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'startGame'

Code for the button:

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startGame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="TheGame"
        android:text="Start!" />

Comment: Error is just above your comment